# SQL collation issue

Tags: mysql, collation

I have a php code which parse XML files and store the parsed information in my database(MySQL) on my Linux server.
all my tables collation is 'utf8_unicode_ci' even my database collation is 'utf8_unicode_ci'
I have a lot of languages in my XML files (Turkish, Swedish, french, ...) and I want the special characters in these languages to be stored in their original form but my problem is that an XML pattern like this :

```
<match date="24.08.2012" time="17:00" status="FT" venue="Stadiumi Loro Boriçi (Shkodër)" venue_id="1557" static_id="1305963" id="1254357">
```

the venue value will be stored in my database like this:

```
Stadiumi Loro BoriÃ§i (ShkodÃ«r)
```

can anybody help me to store the value in my database as it is ???

Comment: which collation is your database?

Comment: I said that it is utf8_unicode_ci

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use "SET NAMES utf8" command before the query. As the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html) says:

> SET NAMES indicates what character set the client will use to send SQL statements to the server.

I tried to imitate your case. Created a table test1:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test1`;
CREATE TABLE `test1` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And tried to insert a string with French special characters and Chinese. For me it worked ok even without `SET NAMES`.

```
<?php
$str = "çëÙùÛûÜüÔô汉语漢語";

try {

      $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'user', '');
      $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

      $conn->exec("SET NAMES utf8");
      $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO test1 SET value = :value');
      $stmt->execute(array('value' => $str));

      //select the inserted row
      $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE id = :id');
      $stmt->execute(array('id' => 1));
      while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            print_r($row);
      }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

It worked correctly, printing this:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [value] => çëÙùÛûÜüÔô汉语漢語
)
```

Also when you are testing don't read directly from console, redirect the output into a file and open it with a text editor:

```
php test.php > 1.txt
```